# Unable to login facebook auth in the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I have implemented facebook login in flutter app with firebase using **flutter_login_facebook** this package . And getting success as response from facebook api , while signin with credential it shows that the token is invalid

**[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Invalid access_token, error code 43**

Future signinWithFacebook() async {
// by default we request the email and the public profile

```
final fb = FacebookLogin();
final response = await fb.logIn(
  permissions: [
    FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
    FacebookPermission.email,
    FacebookPermission.userFriends
    // FacebookPermission.userGender,
    // FacebookPermission.userBirthday
    // FacebookPermission.pagesShowList,
  ],
);

switch (response.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.success:
    develop.log('Facebook login ${response}');
    final accessToken = response.accessToken;

    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential( //*exception occurs here *
      FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken!.token),
    );
    return userCredential.user!;

  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancel:
    throw 'Login canceled by the user';

  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    throw FirebaseAuthException(
      code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN',
      message: response.error?.developerMessage,
    );

  default:
    throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

}

i am not able to figure out is this error from facebook or firebase .

*I have checked the app secret and app id and checked the steps to implement fb login earlier it was working fine *